# How to build a multi pages application by vite2 and vue3？

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I built a multi-page app with Vue CLI and Vue 2 by changing `vue.config.js` like below:

```js
pages: {
    index: {
      entry: './src/pages/index/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'index page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    admin: {
      entry: './src/pages/admin/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'admin page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'admin']
    }
},
...
```

But how do I build a multi-page app with Vite and Vue 3?

[image]

This is my Directory Structure.
I edited the vite.config.js like this:

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
const { resolve } = require('path')
/**
 * @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
 */
export default {
  plugins: [vue()],
  build:{
    rollupOptions:{
      input:{
        main:resolve(__dirname,'index.html'),
        admin:resolve(__dirname,'src/admin/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it returns errors when i build and i counld not open the admin page by localhost:3000/admin/index.html.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could create two separate `index.html` for each entry point. For example, `<projectRoot>/index.html` imports `<projectRoot>/main.js`, while a nested `<projectRoot>/admin/index.html` imports `<projectRoot>/admin/main.js`.

Consider the following directory structure:

```
|-package.json
|-vite.config.js
|-index.html
|-main.js
|-admin/
|---index.html
|---main.js
```

You'd use this config to create the [multi-page app](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app):

```js
// vite.config.js
const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        admin: resolve(__dirname, 'admin/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works very well, but do you know how to specify the chunk names? If the nested page shares any code with the main can you get 2 modules/chunks generated ie index.js and admin.js which both may use common.js? I want to know if you can either duplicate common.js or set a predefined name? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on created VueJS template my `vite.config.js` looks little differently then from the accepted answer. Maybe it could help somebody

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

import { resolve } from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        admin: resolve(__dirname, 'admin.html')
      }
    }
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: '@usenpm  "@/styles/style.scss" as *;'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```