# CSS Not Loading in HTML Files in Subdirectories When Built with Vite

Tags: javascript, html, css, vite

I am building a static website on Vite, to be deployed with Netlify and I'm nearly to the point of going live, however I am having issues with specific 'blog post' pages not correctly linking to the CSS and JS files.

I know that when you build the Vite project, it creates a new JS and CSS file with a hash value. And when looking at the built index.html file I can see the CSS & JS file being linked properly:

The CSS link (in the working file): `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` which is then converted to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main-cbf25e64.css">` in the built file.

The same is true for the JS file within the index.html.

However, on the individual blog posts (which, I think importantly are in a subfolder) after the build it is still: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` (same for the JS file)

I'm thinking just to create a script to update all blog posts after the build, but before I get into the weeds on that I'm just wondering if there is a better/built-in way.

Thank you so much

The structure of the project is as follows:

```
-Public
 --blog
  ---individual-blog-post.html
 --index.html
 --style.css
 --main.js
```

Comment: Hey! Check out Vite's guide on building a multipage app. It might help you with the issue. https://vitejs.dev/guide/build#multi-page-app

Comment: First, know that you're not doing anything wrong. That error would be expected in the `individual-blog-post.html` file, since the correct link to the `style.css` file would be `../style.css` to go up the directory where your css file is present. Now, there was someone else who had this problem before, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979500/15994121)